# SBT. runMain with arguments inside task

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a simple task:

```
lazy val myCustomTask = TaskKey[Unit]("description of my task")
myCustomTask := {
    val arg = "arg1"   // Not used yet
    (runMain in Compile).toTask(" com.company.Main").value
}
```

It works fine.
But i need to pass some arguments. If i do this:

```
(runMain in Compile).toTask(s" com.company.Main $arg").value
```

I get error:

> error: Illegal dynamic reference: arg
>   (runMain in Compile).toTask(s" com.company.Main $arg").value
>   ^
>   [error] Type error in expression

How to pass argument correctly?

**P.S.** Sorry for my english, it's not my native.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this problem with dynamic task:

```
lazy val myCustomTask = taskKey[Unit]("description of my task")
myCustomTask := Def.taskDyn {
    val arg = "arg1"

    Def.task {
        (runMain in Compile).toTask(s" com.company.Main $arg").value
    }
}.value
```